# Python bot. Отправка аудио

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я делаю бота для вк(первый раз). Хотел создать говорилку. Но эта функция не хочет загружать аудио слишком маленького размера(по крайней мере 1 КБ не загрузил, а 344 КБ загрузил)

```
def load(id):
    audio = open("saying.mp3", "rb")

    a = vk.method("audio.getUploadServer")
    b = requests.post(a["upload_url"], files={"file": audio}).json()
    c = vk.method("audio.save", {"server":b["server"],"hash":b["hash"],"audio": b["audio"], "artist": "TEST", "title":"Говорилка"})
    d = "audio{}_{}".format(c["owner_id"], c['id'])
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'attachment': d, 'message': 'Done'})
    return d
```

Вот код говорилки:

```
from gtts import gTTS

def speech(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='ru')
    tts.save('saying.mp3')
```

Вот ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может можно как-то отправлять не как аудио сообщение, а как голосовое сообщение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена другим способом. Я просто стал загружать не музыку, а аудио сообщения от своего профиля.

```
from gtts import gTTS
import vk_api
import json
import requests


def speech(text, id, lang):
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login='your_login', password='your_password')
    vk._auth_token()
    if len(text.split()) <= 500:
        # Создание файла
        tts = gTTS(text=text, lang=lang)
        name = "say.mp3"
        tts.save(name)
        # Загрузка файла на сервер
        url = vk.method('docs.getUploadServer', {'type': 'audio_message'})['upload_url'] # получаем ссылку для загрузки файла
        files = [('file', (name, open(name, 'rb')))]  # записываем этот файл в переменную
        url_2 = requests.post(url, files=files).text  # загружаем файл и получаем ответ
        RESPONSE = json.loads(url_2)['file']  # получаю ответ и перевожу в json
        RESPONSE_2 = vk.method('docs.save', {'file': RESPONSE})
        _id = RESPONSE_2[0]['id']
        owner_id = RESPONSE_2[0]['owner_id']  # получаю owner_id файла
        document = 'doc%s_%s' % (str(owner_id), str(_id))  # формирую ссылку на документs
        href = RESPONSE_2[0]['url']
        href = [i for i in href]
        href = href[14:]
        href = ''.join(href)
        return href
```